# What are the steps necessary in creating a community driven website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello people from StackOverflow!

I come to you with yet another question. :)
As stated in some of my previous questions, I'm interested in creating a website that handles jobs and company openings for people to browse. I intend to have a way for people to upload CV's, apply to a position, and have companies post jobs as well.

Since I've never done a project of this scope before, I fear that I may be neglecting certain things that are a must for a web-targeted application.

I realize that is a very broad question, perhaps too broad to even answer. However, I'd really like someone to provide just a little input on this. :)

What things do I need to have in mind when I create a website of this type?

I'm going to be using ASP.Net and C#.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, the website is going to be local to a country in eastern europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with the free "Job Site Starter Kit":

http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/job/

```
* Enables job seekers to post resumes
* Enables job seekers to search for job postings
* Enables employers to enter profile of their company
* Enables employers to post one or more job postings
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking on careers.stackoverflow then? :)

One of the biggest things, is not even a technical thing to be thinking about - how are you going to pull in enough users to make the site take off?

It's a bit of a chicken and egg situation - if you don't have recruiters on the site, noone's CV will get viewed. If you don't have CVs listed, recruiters won't use the site. So first and foremost, you need to be thinking about how you will build up a community.

- the site must have a good, easy to use, user experience. Make it easy for everyone to achieve what they want.
- what makes your site stand out from others? why should people use yours instead of another one?

Comment: +1 Spot on, and my sentiment completely. This is really the case with any new site that depends on content to be successful. How do you get it there in the first place? And you need to, as you only have one shot at attracting users. Once they see there isn't any content, they're gone. And likely won't come back.

Comment: Socialize it and make it fun to use - none of the others do that! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you need a community. It doesn't really matter which one, but it would help if you were also a member of this community. Let's take Underwater Basket Weavers. Then find a problem that this community has or something this community needs to share. Almost invariably it involves information exchange but in some cases it may actually be service based. Then focus your efforts on solving or supplementing that issue. For our Underwater Basket Weavers, we may have a need to share techniques on how to weave specific materials, where to get materials. How could they share this information and how could you make it interesting to them?

Know your audience. Learn their issues. Apply yourself to filling that void.